# CakePHP: creating an array field that holds the count of specific values from another array

Tags: arrays, cakephp, count

I'm working with someone else's CakePHP code, with minimal knowledge of PHP, so this may be a very basic question.

Within a controller, the following code begins to create an array that's then passed to a .ctp file:

```
$prefs_by_user = $this->PanelPref->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'UserTimeSlot.day_time_slot_id', 'PanelPref.panel_id', 'Panel.name',
        'COUNT(DISTINCT PanelPref.user_id) AS panels_int' ,
```

Within PanelPref are panel ratings that may equal 1, 2, or 3. I would like to add fields that count how many people have given this particular panel each rating. I attempted this:

```
        'COUNT(PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 3) AS rated_three',
        'COUNT(PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 2) AS rated_two',
        'COUNT(PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 1) AS rated_one',
```

but all that does is count `PanelPref.panel_rating_id` and since there are as many ratings as there are users, all the variables end up with the same value.

I've tried using `==` and `=>` instead of `=`, but they return errors.

I've tried `COUNT(PanelPref.panel_rating_id WHERE PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 3) AS rated_three` and gotten an error.

I've tried using array_count_values but it doesn't seem to work within the array fields (and I'm probably not using it properly anyway).

Any thoughts on how to make this work? It's not vital but I would really like to have it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace those with these three:

```
'SUM(CASE PanelPref.panel_rating_id WHEN 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rated_three',
'SUM(CASE PanelPref.panel_rating_id WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rated_two',
'SUM(CASE PanelPref.panel_rating_id WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS rated_one'
```

Those items are part of the "fields" array, which correspond to the SELECT area of a generic T-SQL code block. What it looks like you want is a count of ratings for the item, and so this sum of case is the sort of hacky workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
'SUM(PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 3) AS rated_three',
'SUM(PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 2) AS rated_two',
'SUM(PanelPref.panel_rating_id = 1) AS rated_one',
```